# How to display radioboxes or textboxes when an option is chosen in a select tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a select element with 3 options

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option id="ll1">Parents</option>
    <option id="ll2">Relatives</option>
    <option id="ll3">Non - Relatives</option>
</select>
```

And I want to display these other elements when an option is chosen. Option parents will show div l1, Relatives option will show div l2, Non - Relative option will show div l3

```
<div id="l1">
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Both Parents">Both Parents
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Father Only">Father Only
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Mother Only">Mother Only
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" checked="checked">None
</div>
<br>
<div id="l2">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Reason">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="l3">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Reason">
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var strSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;

        if(strSelected == "ll1") {
            document.getElementById("l1").element.style.display = "block";
        } else if(strSelected == "ll2") {
            document.getElementById("l2").element.style.display = "block";
        } else if(strSelected == "ll3") {
            document.getElementById("l3").element.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

    9. Living with:
<select onchange="myFunction()" id="mySelect">
    <option id="ll1">Parents</option>
    <option id="ll2">Relatives</option>
    <option id="ll3">Non - Relatives</option>
</select>
<div id="l1"> 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Both Parents"> Both Parents
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Father Only"> Father Only
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Mother Only"> Mother Only 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" checked="checked"> None 
</div><br>
<div id="l2">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br>
</div>
<div id="l3">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far? Explain what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I tried some javascript that were tried by others but it doesnt work on mine

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Without showing us an attempt, it is very difficult to diagnose what you are doing wrong. Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I now have show my work

Comment: @MickaelLeger I would like it to have it in JavaScript only for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with javascript.

The logic is :

- You display your select and hide the other div with css for example (`display : none`)
- You use the `onchange` trigger so every time your change the selected option, you will do something
- Each time the selected option change, just check the current selected id and according to the result you show the div you want and hide the others

```js
function displayBlock(opt) {
  var selected_id = opt[opt.selectedIndex].id; 
  
  switch (selected_id) {
    case 'll1':
      document.getElementById('l1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('l2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l3').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case 'll2':
      document.getElementById('l1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l2').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('l3').style.display = 'none';
       break;
    case 'll3':
      document.getElementById('l1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l3').style.display = 'block';
      break;
    default :
      document.getElementById('l1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('l3').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#l1, #l2, #l3 { display: none; }
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="displayBlock(this);">
  <option id="none">-----------</option>
  <option id="ll1">Parents</option>
  <option id="ll2">Relatives</option>
  <option id="ll3">Non - Relatives</option>
</select>

<div id="l1"> 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Both Parents"> Both Parents
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Father Only"> Father Only
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Mother Only"> Mother Only 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" checked="checked"> None 
</div><br>
<div id="l2">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Specify (l2)">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br>
</div>
<div  id="l3">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Specify (l3)">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  console.log(elem.value);
  if (elem.value == "Parents") {
    document.getElementById('l1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('l2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('l3').style.display = "none";
  }
  if (elem.value == "Relatives") {
    document.getElementById('l1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('l2').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('l3').style.display = "none";
  }
  if (elem.value == "Non - Relatives") {
    document.getElementById('l1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('l2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('l3').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#l1,
#l2,
#l3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="showDiv(this)">
  <option id="ll1">Parents</option>
  <option id="ll2">Relatives</option>
  <option id="ll3">Non - Relatives</option>
</select>


<div id="l1">
  <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Both Parents"> Both Parents
  <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Father Only"> Father Only
  <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Mother Only"> Mother Only
  <input type="radio" name="livingwith" checked="checked"> None
</div><br>
<div id="l2">
  <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Specify">
  <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br>
</div>
<div id="l3">
  <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Specify">
  <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I would just hide the other options. And listen to the change of the select.

```js
  let select = document.getElementById("mySelect")
 select.addEventListener("change", function(){ 

 let opt1 = document.getElementById("l1");
 let opt2 =document.getElementById("l2");
 let opt3 =document.getElementById("l3");
 if(select.value === "Parents"){
 opt1.style.display = "block";
  opt2.style.display = "none";
   opt3.style.display = "none";
 }
  if(select.value === "Relatives"){
 opt1.style.display = "none";
  opt2.style.display = "block";
   opt3.style.display = "none";
 }
  if(select.value === "NonRelatives"){
 opt1.style.display = "none";
  opt2.style.display = "none";
   opt3.style.display = "block";
 }
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
        <option id="ll1" value="Parents">Parents</option>
        <option id="ll2" value="Relatives">Relatives</option>
        <option id="ll3" value="NonRelatives">Non - Relatives</option>
    </select>
  
    <div id="l1" style="display: block;"> 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Both Parents"> Both Parents
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Father Only"> Father Only
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" value="Mother Only"> Mother Only 
    <input type="radio" name="livingwith" checked="checked"> None 
    </div><br>
    <div id="l2" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br>
    </div>
    <div  id="l3" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Specify">
    <input type="text" name="livingwithnonrelative" placeholder="Reason"> <br><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
document.getElementById("l1").element.style.display = "block";
```

With the function getElementById you get the element with that id, why after get the element you write

```
.element
```

That is not necesary you have got the element, you should write:

```
document.getElementById("l1").style.display = "block";
```

And that with l2 and l3 elements too